# WebdriverIO - Why am I not getting any duration fields in my custom reporter

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, webdriver-io, reporters

I've created a custom reporter for my WebdriverIO v4 project. Right now, I am trying to get the run duration of suites and tests. However, the information that each event gives me does not include a duration field. I've seen many examples where the duration seems to be given by default (such as [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@wdio/reporter) and [here](https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/tree/master/packages/wdio-reporter)).  How could I see how long each suite/test takes to complete?

Here's an example of the information that returns at the end of a suite:

```
{ type: 'test:end',
  title: 'should verify that link is actionable',
  parent: 'Link',
  fullTitle: 'Link should verify that link is actionable',
  pending: false,
  file: 'C:\\Users\\tests\\Login\\Link.js',
  cid: '3-1',
  specs:
   [ 'C:\\Users\\tests\\Login\\Link.js' ],
  event: 'test:end',
  runner:
   { '3-1':
      { browserName: 'chrome',
        platform: 'Windows 8.1',
        version: 'latest' } },
  uid: 'should verify that link is actionable21',
  parentUid: 'Link2',
  specHash: '32cc5c1b3a2063ce5a50e407362cfe50' }
```